# error when running npm start & try to create react app with npx

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

**I have tried a lot but always show below error. please help**

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Estj3.png)

or

error-->

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
npm ERR! path E:\chatX
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-17T19_49_37_928Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: From the error, it looks like one of the commands in the start (or related scripts) in package.json is looking for c:\windows\system32\bash.exe but unable to find it there. ENOENT (4058) means that an expected file at a given path is not found.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

1. I just added the following environment path variable:

   ```
   "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
   ```
2. In PowerShell, I ran the following command:

   ```
   npm config set script-shell  "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
   ```